# What to do with pyc files when Django or python is used with Mercurial?

Tags: python, django, mercurial, pyc

Just started to use Mercurial. Wow, nice application. I moved my database file out of the code directory, but I was wondering about the `.pyc` files. I didn't include them on the initial commit. The documentation about the `.hgignore` file includes an example to exclude `*.pyc`, so I think I'm on the right track.

I am wondering about what happens when I decide to roll back to an older fileset. Will I need to delete all the `.pyc` files then? I saw some questions on Stack Overflow about the issue, including one gentleman that found old `.pyc` files were being used. What is the standard way around this?

Comment: Do you use Mercurial under Linux?  And do you use command line `hg` app or some kind of GUI app?

Comment: I prefer setting PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE during development to avoid pyc headaches altogether.

Comment: ->Kirill: I am using Mercurial under MacOS X for Django web development for my medical practice. It is fun watching files come and go in the GUI when the command line hg app works its magic. ->thg435: Thanks for pointing out the PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in ms4py's answer, *.pyc are compiled files that will be regenerated on the fly. You wouldn't want to include these when distributing a project.

However, if it happens you have modules that existed before when you roll back changes and *.pyc files are left lying around, strange bugs can appear as pyc files can be execute even if the original python file doesn't exist anymore. This has bitten me a few times in Django when adding and removing apps in a project and switching branches with git.

To clean things up, you can delete every compiled files in your project's directory by running the following shell command in you project's directory:

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Most `find`s also support `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {} \;`.

Comment: If your code base is bug free this problem does not occur within the default mercurial workflow (because you never import from a *.pyc which has no corresponding *.py).

Comment: OK, so it looks like the right thing to do is do `hg commit` at intervals. If rolling back, run `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete` after the rollback as an option. It is good to exclude *.pyc files in general from Mercurial.

Comment: @ms4py It can also happen if you move a file from one package to another.

Answer (score 5):

Usually you are safe, because `*.pyc` are regenerated if the corresponding `*.py` changes its content.

It is problematic if you delete a `*.py` file and you are still importing from it in another file. In this case you are importing from the `*.pyc` file if it is existing. But this will be a bug in your code and is not really related to your mercurial workflow.

**Conclusion**: Every famous Python library is ignoring their `*.pyc` files, just do it ;)

Comment: I agree. For the most part, things "just work". If you get strange behavior from your project (code being run that you *know* is no longer there, for example), then delete your *.pyc files. Otherwise, don't worry about it.

Comment: If you're deleting modules but still importing them, expecting an ImportError instead of loading an old .pyc file, that's probably a sign you're doing something odd...

Answer (score 3):

For a more general solution, then ask **Mercurial itself** about which files it ignores:

```
$ hg status --ignored
```

You can make the output safe for `xargs` consumption:

```
$ hg status --ignored --no-status -0 | xargs -0 -delete
```

(The `-0` is important to handle files with spaces in the name.) You can install this as a post-update hook:

```
[hooks]
post-update = hg status --ignored --no-status -0 | xargs -0 -delete
```

Finally, Mercurial comes with a [purge extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension) that does something similar:

```
$ hg purge --all
```

will delete both untracked and ignored files. If you're okay with losing untracked files, then that command is probably the easiest for you, in particular because it also works on Windows where `xargs` may be hard to come by.

Answer (score 0):

Sure if you have a `.pyc` file from an older version of the same module python will use that.  Many times I have wondered why my program wasn't reflecting the changes I made, and realized it was because I had old pyc files.

If this means that `.pyc` are not reflecting your current version then yes you will have to delete all `.pyc` files.

If you are on linux you can `find . -name *.pyc -delete`

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP mentions ignoring `.pyc` in VCS already.

Comment: As I understand from the question, @kd4ttc has already done this.